# uiview issue with tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on Xcode 5.1.2 iOS7.My problem is that i want to implement tab bar controller on second view controller . Tab bar controller is implemented successfully.My all view are slightly transparent which inserts in array to tab bar.when i click on tab bar button,first view is visible at behind of every view of tab bar views.so how i can solve this problem.

```
tabbar=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
                UIViewController *first=[[ViewController alloc]init];
                UIViewController *second=[[SearchViewController alloc]init];
                UIViewController *third=[[Party_partner_ViewController alloc]init];
                UIViewController *Fourth=[[My_GrooveViewController alloc]init];
                UIViewController *Fifth=[[More_ViewController alloc]init];
                UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first];
                UINavigationController *firstNavController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];
                UINavigationController *firstNavController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:third];
                UINavigationController *firstNavController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:Fourth];
                UINavigationController *firstNavController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:Fifth];
                NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
                if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
                    self.nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29/255.0f green:29/255.0f blue:29/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
                    self.nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
                }else
                {
                    self.nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29/255.0f green:29/255.0f blue:29/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
                }

                self.nav.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"The Groove";

                    tabbar.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController,firstNavController1, firstNavController2,firstNavController3,firstNavController4, Nil];

                AppDelegate  *mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                // UIWindow *window= [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
                [mainDelegate.window addSubview:tabbar.view];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sure first you can hide or remove your uiview

Comment: You can post it on comment not as a answer. please